# xpath query to check if all xml element have same value

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I have the following xml

```
<collection>
<item>
    <id>001</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>A</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
<item>
    <id>002</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>A</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
<item>
    <id>003</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>B</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
</collection>
```

I need my xpath query to return me "true" if all attr1='A'.
I tried with this but it returns "true" even if only one attr1="A".

```
//item/attr1/text()='A'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current XPath is returning true because there is at least one `attr1` element that has a `text()` value of `A`.

You could test whether the count of `attr1` elements is equal to the count of `attr1` elements that have `text()` with the value `A`:

```
count(//item/attr1) = count(//item/attr1[text() = 'A'])
```

Or you could evaluate an expression to test that there are `not()` any `attr1` elements that are not equal to `A`:

```
not(//item/attr1[not(text() = 'A')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text value of the first node with `attr1` and then to search for nodes with `attr1` with text not equals to that text value:

```
textValue = //item/attr1/text()
//item/attr1[not(text() = textValue)]
```