# xpath check if specified value exists at least once in each subelement

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I have this xml.

```
<collection>
<item>
    <id>001</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>A</attr1>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>B</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
<item>
    <id>002</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>B</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
<item>
    <id>003</id>
    <attributes>
        <attr1>A</attr1>
    </attributes>
</item>
</collection>
```

I need my xpath query to return me "true" if each `item` element contains at least one `attributes/attr1='A'`.
I had a go with this xpath as I tried to elaborate on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935806/xpath-query-to-check-if-all-xml-element-have-same-value) thread (thank you Mads, you answered the wrong question, my bad)

```
//item/attributes/attr1/text()='A'
```

Comment: Hello Mads, didn't get your reaction to my question. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Which version of xpath is available to you?

Comment: I'm using xpath 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 2 and later you can literally write `every $item in //item satisfies $item/attributes/attr1 = 'A'`.

For XPath 1.0 I tend to use a negation, I think: `not(//item[not(attributes/attr1 = 'A')])`. But I am usually thinking in XPath 3 these days so better let someone who prefers XPath 1 or feels he/she can (still?) juggle with the versions answer that.

Comment: And what if I wanted to achieve this in xpath 1.0?

Comment: @JamesTaylor, I tend to use a negation for XPath 1.0 but I am not used to think and express things anymore in that version. See the edit and let's wait whether someone objects or has better idea.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I checked your answer `not(//item[not(attributes/attr1 = 'A')])` on http://xpather.com/. It works perfect.